# How can I divide up my database into different areas for different kinds of information storage in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

My database has been created with table names looking like this for the user information:

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Membership];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_OAuthMembership];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Roles];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles];
```

Is this somewhat of a standard when it comes to table naming conventions? If I now want
to make some new tables would it be reasonable to also name them things like

```
admin_application
admin_account
```

or do DBAs normally assign tables used to hold different things to different users when they want to group table types?

I would just like to find out how people normally group tables in an application. Am I 
right to assume they are all under one owner in this case dbo or do people leave the 
table names alone and have them stored in different owner accounts?

Comment: Usually the addition of a prefix identifies the table as fulfilling a particular type of purpose in an application (or database in this case!)

Comment: The `[dbo]` is usually added by SSMS as a belt and braces approach to guaranteeing that the correct object is acted on.  `dbo` is a role, though, not a user.

Comment: `dbo` is actually a user, not a role.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the best way is to use schemas to divide logically grouped tables. Good example of this is Adventure works database you can download from [CodePlex](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/). They have several schemas for different parts of the company such as Person, Production, Purcahsing, Sales and other. See [more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124894%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) on how MS designed this DB.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at schemas:

```
create schema webpages authorization dbo;
GO

create table webpages.Membership (...
create table webpages.OAuthMembership (...

create schema admin authorization dbo;
GO

create table admin.application (...
```

It used to be that before SQL Server 2005, you needed to create a database user in order to create a schema. However, since then, you can create schemas for organizational purposes. Schemas cannot contain schemas, so it's a single level. Schemas can contain any database object, i.e. tables, stored procedures, etc..

Schemas need to have an owner, hence the `authorization` bit above. Specifying `dbo` here will make it the same as if you had created it in the `dbo` schema.